# Prometheus function for counter metrics per unit of time

Tags: prometheus

I have a counter metrics configured for my application, and I am monitoring it on grafana using promethus.
Metrics basically would go on accumulating as its a counter. But I am more interested in counts for a short period of time, say 1 minute. Like for eg, number of service hits in 1 minute period.

So I try with:

```
delta(mymetrics[1m])
```

But I am not sure if it would give correct picture as prometheus documentation says that delta is to be used only for gauges.

What can be a better way of achieving it?

Comment: You can try with the rate() function. 
Please refer https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/

Comment: rate is count/sec, while I am looking for absolute count value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`increase(mymetrics[1m])` is what you're looking for. As you say, `delta` should never be used with counters.

Comment: increase can be a good fit here, but increase gives the average of increments in the time window. So if in timewindow values attained are v1,v2,v3,v4, increase would give ((v1-v2)+(v2-v3)+(v3-v4))/3 ie (v1-v4)/3

Comment: It'll return (roughly speaking) v1-v4 extrapolated out to the whole time window, seehttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67Ulrq6DxwA